# How to send an HTTP GET request using Firebase and Angular?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, cors, httprequest, ibm-watson

My app uses IBM Watson Speech-to-Text, which requires an access token. From the command line I can get the access token with curl:

```
curl -X GET --user my-user-account:password \
--output token \
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api"
```

When I make an HTTP request using Angular's `$http` service I get a CORS error:

```
var data = {
  user: 'my-user-account:password',
  output: 'token'
};

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api',
    data: data,
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  console.log("HTTP GET successful");
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  console.log("HTTP GET failed");
});
```

The error message says:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

As I understand, it's not possible to do CORS from Angular; CORS has to be done from the server. I know how to do CORS with Node but I'm using Firebase as the server.

Firebase has [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) about making HTTP requests with CORS. The documentation says to write this:

```
$scope.getIBMToken = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {

  });
});
```

First, that doesn't work. The error message is `functions is not defined`. Apparently `functions` isn't in the Firebase library? I call Firebase from `index.html`:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

My controller injects dependencies for `$firebaseArray`, `$firebaseAuth`, and `$firebaseStorage`. Do I need to inject a dependency for `$firebaseHttp` or something like that?

Second, how do I specify the method ('GET'), the URL, and the data (my account and password)?

Comment: The short answer is, that token-generator endpoint isn’t CORS-enabled—that is, it doesn’t support receiving cross-origin requests from frontend JavaScript code running in a browser—and so the only way you’re going to be able to call it is either: (A) instead make the request from your backend code; or (B) set up a CORS proxy using the code from https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/ or such, and then have your frontend code make the request through that CORS proxy

Comment: Since that API requires authentication but apparently requires you send those credentials as part of a `GET` request, then you add an `Authorization: Basic bXk…` request header to the request, where the `bXk…` is replaced with the Base64-encoding of your actual account name and password in *account:password* form—but if you try that you’ll find it also fails, again with a 401. That’s because adding the `Authorization` header to the request triggers browsers to first automatically do a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request—before trying the `GET` request in the code—and that preflight fails.

Comment: The reason the CORS preflight fails is, that token-generator endpoint apparently requires authentication for `OPTIONS` requests (which it shouldn’t), but the browser doesn’t add an `Authorization` header to that preflight `OPTIONS` request—because the entire purpose of the preflight is to ask that server if it’s OK receiving cross-origin requests which include that header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use Cloud Functions for Firebase, which enable running Node functions from the server. Then you use the Node module `request` to send the HTTP request from Node.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send credentials with angular, just set `withCredentials=true`. I am also using CORS with Angular v4, for your HTTP header error, you are right. Header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` must be added on server side, check if you have settings in your api to allow certain domains, urls, pages, because google api's has this function, so check where you get token there should be some settings.

Here is example, how I am calling API with CORS, using typescript:

```
broadcastPresense(clientId: string) {
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json','withCredentials':'true'});
    return this.http.post('http://localhost/api.php',
    {
       'jsonrpc': '2.0',
       'method': 'somemethod',
       'params': {'client_id': clientId},
       'id': CommonClass.generateRandomString(16)
    },{headers: headers, withCredentials:true}).map(
        (res: Response) => {
           console.log(res);
           const data = res.json();
           console.log(data);
           if (data.error == null) {
               return data.result;
           } else if (data.error != null) {
              throw data.error;
           }
           throw data.error;
       }
   ).catch(
      (error) => {
         this.router.navigate(['/error',3],{queryParams: {desc:'Server error'}});
         return Observable.throw(error);
      }
   );
}
```

Hope it helps :)